# Not writing to CSV after parsing with Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a feeling I am making a stupid mistake. I am trying to scrape some data from a website and I can parse the data but it doesn't write to csv. I am a complete beginner to python and I am scratching my head over this.

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
import csv
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.example.com/"

total_pages = 100

def parse_content(r):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    g_data = soup.find_all('ul', {"class": "searchResults"})

    for item in g_data:
        for li in item.findAll('li'):
            for resultnameh2 in li.findAll('h2'):
                for resultname in resultnameh2.findAll('a'):
                    cname = resultname.text
                    
        for resultAddress in li.findAll('p', {"class": "resultAddress"}):
            caddress = resultAddress.text.replace('Get directions','').strip()  
            
        for resultContact in li.findAll('ul', {"class": "resultContact"}):
            for resultContact in li.findAll('a', {"class": "resultMainNumber"}):
                ccontact = resultContact.text

for page in range(1, total_pages):
    response = requests.get(base_url + '/' + str(page))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        break

    parse_content(response)
    csvdata = parse_content(response)
    
    with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:  
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([csvdata])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to return values

```
import requests
import csv
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.example.com/"

total_pages = 100

def parse_content(r): # you are not returning anything from this function, I will change this function so it will return required values.
    cname=[]
    caddress=[]
    ccontact=[]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    g_data = soup.find_all('ul', {"class": "searchResults"})

    for item in g_data:
        for li in item.findAll('li'):
            for resultnameh2 in li.findAll('h2'):
                for resultname in resultnameh2.findAll('a'):
                    cname.append(resultname.text) # As it is list you need to append all these values

        for resultAddress in li.findAll('p', {"class": "resultAddress"}):
            caddress.append(resultAddress.text.replace('Get directions','').strip())  

        for resultContact in li.findAll('ul', {"class": "resultContact"}):
            for resultContact in li.findAll('a', {"class": "resultMainNumber"}):
                ccontact.append(resultContact.text)

    return cname,caddress,ccontact

for page in range(1, total_pages):
    response = requests.get(base_url + '/' + str(page))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        break

    parse_content(response)
    cname,caddress,ccontact = parse_content(response)
    print(cname)
    print(caddress)
    print(ccontact)
    #print whatever you like from above lists 
    with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:  
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([csvdata])
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting content into the csv now but the format is wrong, all the records are all in one value.

Comment: try to debug this by printing each value inside for loop..and see what values are coming, try to print list and see if is getting appended or not. you are almost there.

Comment: I have been trying but no luck. Each item has three values and I want three values for each row in my csv: `cname, caddress, ccontact` I cant seem to get it right.

Comment: @Bruno which url you are trying to extract?

Comment: Solved :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The values for `cname`, `caddress`, `ccontact` have been set in context of the function `parse_content` hence are not available in the `for` loop for csv writer.

You will either need to return these values or move the csv writer in `parse_content` method.

Comment: Aha! I see :) Can I assign a variable like this: `ccc = (parse_content(response))` and then use that in the csv writer?

Comment: Yes, you can depending on what you return from `parse_content`.

Comment: I see. I tried this but it didn't work: `for page in range(1, total_pages):
 response = requests.get(base_url + '/' + str(page))
 if response.status_code != 200:
  break

 parse_content(response)
 ccc = (parse_content(response))
 
 with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:  
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  writer.writerow([ccc])`

Comment: You are not returning anything from `parse_content` function. And, there is no need to call it two times.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I tried moving the csv writer within `def parse_content(r):` but no luck. Could you please provide me with some sample code? I literally started learning python today :)